# ColorStateList Converter only works in debug mode

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a converter that only works in debug mode. When I generate a Release .apk, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is my code:

```
public class CardapioImageColorConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, ColorStateList>
{
    private static Activity Activity => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity;
    protected override ColorStateList Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ColorStateList color;
        if (value)
            color = Activity.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.cor1,Activity.Theme);
        else
            color = Activity.Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.white, Activity.Theme);

        return color;
    }
}
```

And my axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp">
  <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Icone;ImageTintList CardapioImageColor(Selecionado);"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />  
  <TextView
      local:MvxBind="Text Nome; TextColor CardapioTextColor(Selecionado);"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:textColor="@color/cor1"
      android:textSize="11dp"
      android:layout_weight="1.9"
      android:text="@string/lista_espera"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_tiny"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_tiny" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It works perfectly in debug mode. Do you have any idea why it happens?

Comment: Are you using any third party lib for `Mvx.MvxImageView` ?

Comment: In debug mode try enabling the linker, do you get any errors then?

Comment: I'm using sdk Assemblies only, both cases. DeBug and Release.

Comment: Im using the native Mvx.MvxImageView, from Mvvmcross.Platform

Comment: I have tried put this code to skip linking assemblies, but still not working.

MvvmCross.Binding;MvvmCross.Core;MvvmCross.Plugins;MvvmCross.Platform;MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache;MvvmCross.Plugins.DownloadCache.Droid;MvvmCross.Plugins.File;MvvmCross.Plugins.File.Droid;MvvmCross.Plugins.Json;MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.Droid;MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility;MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Droid;Refit;RefitInternalGenerated;

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution!

I'm using linking, so, the converter wasn't working because the linker was enable.

I put this method in a class called "LinkerPleaseInclude".

```
public void Include(MvxImageView mvxImage)
    {
        mvxImage.ImageTintList = mvxImage.ImageTintList;
    }
```

This class is never actually executed, but when Xamarin linking is enabled it does how to ensure types and properties are preserved in the deployed app.